# select query to match multiple columns with multiple keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a select query that will search a single table for words taken from a user input query string like `"John Doe Engineering"`. The string can consist of a single or multiple words. The query string will be passed into a stored procedure as a parameter. In total there area about 20 columns that need to be searched. My first thought was something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%John%' OR FirstName LIKE '%Doe%' OR FirstName LIKE '%Engineering%'
WHERE LastName LIKE '%John%' OR LastName LIKE '%Doe2%' OR LastName LIKE '%Engineering%'
WHERE Manager LIKE '%John%' OR Manager LIKE '%Doe%'OR Manager LIKE '%Engineering%'
WHERE Department LIKE '%John%' OR Department LIKE '%Doe%'OR Department LIKE '%Engineering%'
--repeat for 16 more table columns
```

But I'm not sure how to best generate the query syntax based upon the user query string input. Furthermore this seems like it would be a highly inefficient query. Would it be better to look at using `full text search` in this case? I'm wondering what the best approach might be?

Comment: SQL Server has a feature called full text search.  Probably what you want here.

Comment: I'm thinking "full text search".

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- Got you by 3 seconds! :D

Comment: @Hogan It's a great day when you can beat Gordon.  Its like dunking on Michael Jordan

Comment: Agree with full text search. Definitely don't do it the way you suggest in the question as it will be very susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: WHERE  CONCAT(FirstName,LastName,Manager,Deparment) LIKE '%...%'

Comment: or combining both: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1865426/3270427

Comment: @McNets terrible advice. By making calculations like that - adding columns and comparing the result, you can slow performance to a crawl

Comment: @Andy Nichols, Could you explain how it would be susceptible to Sql injection attacks? The query string will be passed to a SP as a parameter, I thought that eliminated that risk?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk more than 24 * 3 LIKE '%%' ?

Comment: @PixelPaul, by query string, do you mean the SQL statement? If so then a user input containing `';` then some malicious SQL could execute that malicious SQL.

Comment: But I could be wrong. I don't fully understand where the SQL is being built and whether it is executed with @sp_executesql or not

Comment: @Andy Nichols, I'm sorry I meant the user keyword search string will be passed to a SP as a parameter.

Comment: yes, it is worse, you are making a concatination for each column. You are also running into problems with null values

Comment: @PixelPaul. The part I don't understand is how you get from `John Doe Engineering` passed in as a parameter to the LIKE statements. That's the part where you have to be careful.

Comment: @PixelPaul there is no dynamic sql here. So there will be no sql injection

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- you understand!

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said - Full text search is probably the best solution for this type of thing. That said, I thought it would be fun to offer a T-SQL solution.

**Quick Disclaimer 1**

*I would strongly encourage you not to use the solutions below - this was intended to be a fun little SQL exercise; the performance would be bad. Also - I demonstrate two very efficient ways to split a string: one using Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K, the other technique using PARSENAME *

**Quick Disclaimer 2**

I should point out a problem with concatenating the columns into a single string as a couple people suggested -- it can lead to false positives; consider the following query:

```
DECLARE @search varchar(100) = 'ab';

WITH sampleData AS (SELECT fn, ln FROM (VALUES ('aa', 'bb'), ('cc', 'dd')) t(fn,ln))
SELECT * 
FROM sampleData
WHERE CONCAT(fn,ln) LIKE '%'+@search+'%';
```

The above query will return the first record even though the "ab" does not exist in either column. For that reason you would change the WHERE (or CHARINDEX in John's example) to look like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(fn, '|||', ln) LIKE '%'+@search+'%';
```

**My Solutions**

```
-- SAMPLE DATA 
-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @employees TABLE 
(
  FirstName  varchar(100),
  LastName   varchar(100),
  Manager    varchar(100),
  Department varchar(100)
);

INSERT @employees
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  VALUES 
    ('bob', '****', 'ddd', 'sss'),
    ('fff', 'fred', 'obx', 'ccc'),
    ('Sue', 'abcd', 'ddd', 'zzz'),
    ('ddd', 'dcba', '123', 'fobbb')
) xx(x1, x2, x3, x4);

-- Solution #1: when @search has <= 4 "items"
-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @search varchar(100) = 'xx bb ff zz';

SELECT e.*
  --,PARSENAME(REPLACE(@search,' ','.'), N) AS matchedPattern
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) t(n)
CROSS JOIN @employees e
WHERE 
  CHARINDEX
  (
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@search,' ','.'), N), 
    CONCAT(FirstName, '|||', LastName, '|||', Manager, '|||', Department)
  ) > 0;

-- Solution #2: when @search has (or can have) > 4 "items"
-------------------------------------------------

-- for this you will need delimitedsplit8k: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
SELECT e.*
FROM dbo.delimitedsplit8k(@search, ' ')
CROSS JOIN @employees e
WHERE 
  CHARINDEX
  (
    item, 
    CONCAT(FirstName, '|||', LastName, '|||', Manager, '|||', Department)
  ) > 0;
```

Comment: the idea of combining the columns is terrible. It will cause slow performance. As i mentioned in my comment above

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - this is why I said " Full text search is probably the best solution" then added that I was including a T-SQL solution "for fun." You offered nothing other than a comment that everyone here, including the OP, already knew. I'll be interested in the solution that you post....

Comment: you are actually down voting my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509024/get-string-between-2-characters-that-repeats-several-times-in-sql-server/42509706#comment72537334_42509706) to another question in revenge of me down voting this ?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if you're going to provide a knowingly inefficient solution, you should probably also provide an efficient solution as well.  A bad solution won't help anyone that comes across this in the future.

Comment: user2366842 - first sentence - I suggested Full text indexing;  I can't think of a faster solution for this. @t-clausen.dk - if you were read my entire post you would agree there is a lot of extremely useful SQL knowledge there. E.g observe how I split a string using parsename and the values constructor - that's MY technique and represents the fastest pre-2016 way to split a string known to man for when there are  <= 4 items/tokens; not even a CLR can touch it. Yet you voted my answer down. Are you trying to discourage people with an advanced level of T-SQL knowledge from posting?